# QGIS: Accessing layer's CRS from expression and/or PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, field-calculator

How can I access the current feature's/layer's CRS from an QGIS expression, or from a custom expression in PyQGIS?

In my expression, I use the following to buffer a (currently lat-long-specified) feature in map units (m).

```
...buffer(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326',@project_crs),250,1)...
```

I'd like to generalize this to work with any layer, whatever its layer CRS is, i.e. without hardcoding the `'EPSG:4326'`.  But there doesn't seem to be a `@layer_crs` variable. Is there some other way to access this using core expression functions and variables?

As an alternative, I'm open to (and might even prefer) a PyQGIS solution that can be put into a custom function. But (I may be wrong), the `QgsFeature` passed as the `feature` parameter in an expression custom function does not know its (source) CRS or even its layer.

I've also looked at the optional `context` parameter to a custom function, but have gotten lost whether I can shovel through the `QgsExpressionContext` object this provides to find the parent layer and its source CRS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### For QGIS >= v3.18.0

You can use the `@layer_crs` variable in your expression.

### For QGIS < v3.18.0

There is not a `layer_crs`, but we can use the 'crs' layer property:

```
layer_property(  @layer , 'crs' )
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Does `@layer` instead of `@layer_name` work also? I think that should be best practice as it avoids a roundtrip over the layer store and possibly ambiguous name resolution.

Comment: It works as well, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There is a `@layer_crs` nowadays :)

Comment: I'll update the answer, thanks @bugmenot123.